# How do add multiple fields to a Form when trying to validate data?

Tags: python, django

What is the best way to have the IP address be included with the Form is_valid. Let me start with some code examples.

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from testpost.views import TestPost

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^djtestforms/', TestPost),
)
```

model.py

```
from django.db import models

class TestPostModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ip_address = models.IPAddressField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.model

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('TestPostModel', [self.id])
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from models import TestPostModel

class TestPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TestPostModel

from forms import TestPostForm
from models import TestPostModel
from django.http import HttpResponse

def TestPost(request):
    f = TestPostForm(request.POST)
    if f.is_valid():
        object = f.save()
        return HttpResponse("That worked")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("That didn't work")
```

My question is when I try to do "f=TestPostForm(request.POST)" what is the best way to have the IP address added to TestPostForm. I was thinking of something along the lines of "f = TestPostForm(request.POST, ip_address=request.META["REMOTE_ADDR"])" but that doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Save with `commit=False`

```
form=TestPostForm(data=request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
  object=form.save(commit=False)
  object.ip_address=request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
  object.save()
```

You will probably need to set `blank=True` in the model or `required=False` in the form for the form to validate

Comment: Since the reason this question was asked was to make the form valid, this code doesn't help at all.  The answer below is the right one.

Answer (score 2):

@czarchaic - Your'e answer gave me a good hint on what to do. I changed the model so that blank=True for ip_address, and then did a

```
f = TestPostForm(request.POST)
f.data['ip_address']=request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

After that is_valid worked. Thanks.